# Page Scroll with Fixed Sidebar

Tags: html, css

I have a simple `position:fixed` sidebar out of the way of page elements. The page scrolls fine, but when I mouse over the fixed sidebar, the page can no longer scroll. Could someone explain why this happens? and how to fix this?

Comment: A link, code, fiddle... something we can test?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because only the part you hover over scrolls. For example if you create an element with "overflow: scroll", when you over over this element, it will scroll and not the whole page. Same thing is happening over here.